# how to put struct data in datastore in go-lang

Tags: google-app-engine, go

how to put struct data in datastore in go-lang: 
//Struct is created.

```
type UserLogin struct{
    userName string
    passWord string
}
//values assigned
```

p1 := UserLogin{"poonam", "mumbai123"}
   p2 := UserLogin{passWord:"mumbai321", userName:"abcd"}

Now how to store/put/save and get above p1, p2 into datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change struct to:

```
type UserLogin struct{
    UserName string
    PassWord string
}
```

needs to be public fields

storing:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
p1 := UserLogin{"poonam", "mumbai123"}
key := datastore.NewKey(c, "UserLogin",p1.UserName, 0, nil)
datastore.Put(c, key,&p1)
```

reading:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)    
key := datastore.NewKey(c, "UserLogin", "", userName, nil)
var ul UserLogin
err := datastore.Get(c, key, &ul)
```

where r is the *http.Request
also you need todo something with error,

Comment: Thank you. Now Want to set cookie if my UserName is "poonam" .                          if p1.UserName == "poonam" {   
  cookie := &http.Cookie{Name:"test", Value:"metcookie", Expires:time.Now().Add(1 + time.Hour), HttpOnly:true}  
 fmt.Fprint(w, "cookie : ",cookie, "\n")   
 http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
fmt.Fprint(w, "This is Poonam ",p1.PassWord, "\n")
}else {fmt.Fprint(w, "else ", "\n") }                                                     Without if condition able to set cookie but in if condition it is not able to set

Comment: How to put username and password into datastore through template?

Comment: How to Create and render basic Form template in Golang?

Comment: hm, i guess you should just follow the getting startet

[https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/handlingforms](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/handlingforms)